# databind slider in xml

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm developing an application using MVVM and have successfully been able to add simple ui elements like button and textinput but now I'm trying to figure out how to bind a [material slider](https://material.io/components/sliders/).

I've been reading up on [listener bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#listener_bindings) and while the xml at a glance appeared to have let me dp the below app:onChange to resemble the addOnChangeListener that you'll see in my "view activity" class (which will work with the addOnChangeListener inside the kotlin file, but I'm unable to get that to work with the direct app:onChange tag inside the xml file.

Any advice or code samples to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

/* xml layout file */

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
android:id="@+id/material_slider_min_temperature"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:valueFrom="1"
android:valueTo="2"
android:stepSize="1"
app:onChange="@{(slider, value, fromUser)-> mViewModel.fireSliderMinRQ(slider,value,fromUser)}"/>
```

/* view model */

```
fun fireSliderMinRQ(slider: Slider, value: Float, fromUser: Boolean){
 //this will not bind correctly, i can't compile and access the parameters 
}
```

/* view activity */

```
this.mSliderMinTemperature!!.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
 this.mTvMinTemperature.text = value.toInt().toString()
  slider.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
   when(event.action){
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
    this.mSliderMaxTemperature!!.isEnabled = true
   }
  }
  false
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

```
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["onValueChangeListener"])
    fun setOnValueChangeListener(slider: Slider, listener: OnValueChangeListener) {
        slider.addOnChangeListener { _: Slider?, value: Float, _: Boolean ->
            listener.onValueChanged(value)
        }
    }


    interface OnValueChangeListener {
        fun onValueChanged(value: Float)
    }
```

in XML:

```
   <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:onValueChangeListener="@{(value)-> vm.onValueChanged(value)}" />
```

in your ViewModel:

```
   fun onValueChanged(value: Float) {
      // use slider's value
   }
```

**Bind Slider and TextView:**

> this.mTvMinTemperature.text = value.toInt().toString()

For set slider's value as text to TextView:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter(
    value = [
        "textViewLabel",
        "valueFormat"
    ], requireAll = false
)
fun setTextViewLabel(
    slider: Slider,
    textViewLabel: TextView,
    valueFormat: String?
) {
    slider.addOnChangeListener { _: Slider?, value: Float, _: Boolean ->
        valueFormat
            ?.let { format ->
                textViewLabel.text = String.format(format, value)
            }
            ?: let { textViewLabel.text = value.toString() }
    }
}
```

Add in XML to Slider:

```
app:textViewLabel="@{yourTextViewId}"
```

Also, you can use @BindingAdapter for set OnTouchListener via XML too.